# Inserting a partial vector of string names into the 1st row and 1st column of a matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, code-request

Given:

```
SeedRandom[6];
mat = RandomInteger[5, {7, 7}];
mat[[1, All]] = {"", a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, b1};
mat[[All, 1]] = {"", a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, b1};
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

I like to produce this:

```
SeedRandom[6]
mat = RandomInteger[5, {7, 7}];
mat[[1, All]] = {"", k0, k1, k2, a4, a5, b1};
mat[[All, 1]] = {"", k0, k1, k2, a4, a5, b1};
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

As is shown, I want to insert a list of string names:

```
pv={k0,k1,k2}`
```

into a row and a column.

Comment: `mat[[1, 2;;4]] = pv; mat[[2;;4, 1]] = pv` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[6];
mat = RandomInteger[5, {7, 7}];
```

If row/column headers are identical and duplicate-free you can use `ReplaceAll`:

```
mat /. Thread[ mat[[1, {2, 3, 4}]]-> {k0, k1, k2}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

In general,

```
mat2 = mat;
mat2[[1, {2, 3, 4}]] = mat2[[{2, 3, 4}, 1]] = {k0, k1, k2};
mat2 // MatrixForm
```

[image]